# unhide div then retain div after page reload

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery script that reveals divs when a selection is made from a select dropdown. It works fine but I was wondering how to keep the divs on the page after a page reload. Here is the script :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    var color = $(this).val();
    if (color == "Yes") {
      $(".box").not(".Yes").hide();
      $(".Yes").show();
    } else if (color == "No") {
      $(".box").not(".No").hide();
      $(".No").show();
    } else {
      $(".box").hide();
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<div>
Is this to be a subdomain?<select name="setweb">
      

  <option selected disabled>Please Select</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>

    </select>
</div>
<br />

<div class="Yes box" style="display:none">
<input type='text' class='text' name='business' size='20' />Enter your subdomain in the text box.





</div>
<div class="No box" style="display:none">
<input type='text' class='text' name='business' size='20' />Enter your domain in the text box.
</div>




<br/>
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: You'd need to store the change somewhere like in a cookie or localstorage.

Comment: Or perform a basic GET or POST Request with PHP...

Answer (score 0):

use local storage

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 if(localStorage.getItem("elementToShow")) {
   $(localStorage.getItem("elementToShow")).show();
  }
  $("select").change(function() {
    var color = $(this).val();
    if (color == "Yes") {
      $(".box").not(".Yes").hide();
      localStorage.setItem("elementToShow", ".Yes");
      $(".Yes").show();
    } else if (color == "No") {
      $(".box").not(".No").hide();
      localStorage.setItem("elementToShow", ".No");
      $(".No").show();
    } else {
      $(".box").hide();
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<div>
Is this to be a subdomain?<select name="setweb">
      

  <option selected disabled>Please Select</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>

    </select>
</div>
<br />

<div class="Yes box" style="display:none">
<input type='text' class='text' name='business' size='20' />Enter your subdomain in the text box.





</div>
<div class="No box" style="display:none">
<input type='text' class='text' name='business' size='20' />Enter your domain in the text box.
</div>




<br/>
```

Comment: Hi, the local storage solution works really well, but when I reload the page and nothing is selected from the dropdown list bar, it still shows the div. How do I hide the div if list bar has no value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies to store some data within page reload. There is not other simple solution for that...

See also https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

you can set cookie on change

```
document.cookie = "select=somevalue"
```

and then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var select = document.cookie.split(";")[0] ? document.cookie.split(";")[0].split("=")[0] : null

    if (select) {
        // manually trigger the change
    }
})
```

**Edit 1**

"There is not other simple solution for that..." ... except for localStorage :D @Nidhin Chandran